# Wamp: www prefixing in url before localhost without htacceess

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

In wamp server project url should be `http://localhost/v1/` but it is prefixing `www.` like this `http://www.localhost/v1/` and it is also not working in firefox only in chrome. 
Is there any wrong with my functions, because other projects are working fine. 
I tried removing these function and redirecting code from `.htaccess`, still no luck.

Config.php

```
function SiteURL(){
    global $Project;
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])){
        $protocol = ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] && $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] != "off") ? "https" : "http";
    }
    else{
        $protocol = 'http';
    }
     $whitelist = array( '127.0.0.1', '::1', 'localhost' ); 
  if( !in_array( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $whitelist) ){
    return $protocol . "://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/".$Project ;
  }else{

    return $protocol . "://localhost/" .$Project ;  
  }

}

function DocURL(){
    global $Project;
  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])){
        $protocol = ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] && $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] != "off") ? "https" : "http";
    }
    else{
        $protocol = 'http';
    }

  $whitelist = array( '127.0.0.1', '::1', 'localhost' ); 
  if( !in_array( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $whitelist) ){

    $Domain = SiteURL() ; 

    $Parse = parse_url($Domain) ;

    $Host = explode(".", $Parse['host']);

    $Subdomain = array("media");

    array_splice($Host, 1, 0, $Subdomain);

    $URL =  implode(".",$Host);

    return $protocol . "://" . $URL."/" ; 

  }else{
    return  $protocol . "://localhost/".$Project; ; 
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Only the home page is redirecting and prefixing www **http://www.localhost/v1/** other pages are fine.

Comment: If it's just Firefox it could be the browser adding in the www, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186383/browsers-adding-www-and-com-to-server-address-automatically

Comment: in chrome its opening but prefixing url with www `http://www.localhost/v1/` and firefox giving this `Firefox can’t find the server at www.localhost.`